# Merging Json objects

Tags: java, json, gson

I have two jsons

```
1. 

{"root": {
    "item": [
        {
            "groupName": "Al Karama Fire Station",
            "vehicleId": 211,
            "speed": 81
        },
        {
            "groupName": "Al Karama Fire Station",
            "vehicleId": 137,
            "speed": 83
        }
    ],
    "rowCount": 2
}}
```

---

```
2. 



       {"root": {
            "item": {
                "groupName": "Al Karama Fire Station",
                "vehicleId": 222,
                "speed": 1
            },
            "rowCount": 1
        }}
```

Ideally second json should give me a list of "item", but its not happening. I need to convert merge the two json to get a combined one.

Expected :

```
{"root": {
    "item": [
        {
            "groupName": "Al Karama Fire Station",
            "vehicleId": 211,
            "speed": 81
        },
        {
            "groupName": "Al Karama Fire Station",
            "vehicleId": 137,
            "speed": 83
        },
        {
            "groupName": "Al Karama Fire Station",
            "vehicleId": 222,
            "speed": 1
       }
    ],
    "rowCount": 3
}}
```

To achieve this I have created the below DTOs.

```
public class ParentDTO {

    private RootDTO root;

    public RootDTO getRoot() {
        return root;
    }
    public void setRoot(RootDTO root) {
        this.root = root;
    }
}

public class RootDTO {
     private List<ItemDTO> item = new ArrayList<ItemDTO>();
     private Integer rowCount;

    public List<ItemDTO> getItem() {
        return item;
    }
    public void setItem(List<ItemDTO> item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
    public Integer getRowCount() {
        return rowCount;
    }
    public void setRowCount(Integer rowCount) {
        this.rowCount = rowCount;
    }
}

public class ItemDTO {

    private String groupName;
    private String vehicleId;
    private Long speed;

    public String getGroupName() {
        return groupName;
    }

    public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
        this.groupName = groupName;
    }

    public String getVehicleId() {
        return vehicleId;
    }

    public void setVehicleId(String vehicleId) {
        this.vehicleId = vehicleId;
    }

    public Long getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(Long speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }
}
```

My problem is, while merging, I am getting

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 2 column 14 path $.root.item
```

If I can get the second json as below, the code works fine.

```
{"root": {
        "item": [
         {
            "groupName": "Al Karama Fire Station",
            "vehicleId": 222,
            "speed": 1
        }
        ],
        "rowCount": 1
    }}
```

Please suggest.

Code to parse Json

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ParentDTO  updatedloginDto2 = gson.fromJson(tmp1, ParentDTO .class);
```

Comment: Can you change the second json to be generated also from an Array (of 1 element)?

Comment: This is coming from an external service

Comment: Ok, that was my guess. So, I think that your better option is doing something like Answer 1. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create two root DTOs - one for a root having a list of children and one for a root having a single child and after unmarshalling the JSON add the "single child" element to the root with the list of children.

*Edit:*

```
public class RootSingleChildDTO {
     private ItemDTO item;
     private Integer rowCount;

    public ItemDTO getItem() {
        return item;
    }
    public void setItem(ItemDTO item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
    public Integer getRowCount() {
        return rowCount;
    }
    public void setRowCount(Integer rowCount) {
        this.rowCount = rowCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: this would increase the latency

Comment: Yes, but it will reflect your actual structure - the "single child" root is *not* structurally identical to the "list of children" root.

Comment: Need a solution, to avoid latency

Comment: Pre-process your JSON, another solution is not possible with your existing code.